# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) with PHPMailer and Outlook SMTP

Tags: php, email, ssl

I am getting SMTP Error with PHP Mailer and Outlook SMTP. I am confused here because it is working fine on localhost with Port number 25 but It is not working on Hosting Server, I have tried all ports with SSL & TLS.

> **Error :** SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

**My Code:**

```
<?php

include("PHPMailer.php"); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "info@neelcomputech.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->Priority    = 1;
$mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';

$mail->From = "info@neelcomputech.com";
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress("info@neelcomputech.com");

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You got Message from Website";
$mail->Body = "testing";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
}

?>
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I have Shared Linux Hosting.

Comment: You already solved the problem?

Comment: @JorgeB., yes I did.

Comment: Put an answer with your resolution.

Comment: @JorgeB., Issue was with Hosting Provider. I contacted them about this and they did some configuration on their Server and its done.

Comment: @JeetenParmar please set an answer stating what happened and you can mark this answer as correct and close this question. Cheers.

Comment: @Martin sorry for the delay. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct.
The issue was with Hosting Provider. I contacted them about this and they did some configuration on their Server and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out my host (Bluehost) blocked outgoing connections on port 465. I will post the solution here in the hope that helps you. But I'm not expert enough to know if it's the same problem or not.

I found a wonderful [how-to](http://aldrin.aquisap.info/2012/08/26/wp-mail-smtp-in-wordpress-hosted-by-bluehost/) which fixed it for me:

1. In your cPanel DNS Zone editor, find the MX (Mail Exchanger) section, and select 'remote mail exchanger'.
2. In the cPanel email accounts section, create the appropriate email address (don't skip this)
3. Don't use "smtp.live.com" as your smtp host. Use the smtp host of your Shared Linux Hosting smtp. I don't know how you will get yours. Mine is boxXXXX.bluehost.com.
4. Set your username and password to be the same as the email account you just set-up in cPanel.

Comment: blocking 465..... pfft.... like saying if you lock your door we'll break your windows `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me.
After many hours, I found the problem, but only works for Cpanel/WHM

- Login into WHM.
- Go to ConfigServer Security & Firewall inside plugins option.
- Click on Firewall configuration
- Filter by SMTP Settings
- Look for SMTP_ALLOWUSER option and add the Cpanel account's username separated by coma
- Restart the Firewall.

If you don't have access to WHM ask your provider.

Hope it helps!