# can't use smtp.gmail using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I know this kind of question asked so many times in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but I looked at most of them and the problem still remains.


I'm using phpMailer to send mail from my site using a gmail account.

When I was using this in localhost, everything was fine and mails was sending correctly, 
But as long as I uploaded my site in remote server, problem revealed itself.


There's `connection timeout(110) error` when I'm using port `465` and `smtp.gmail.com`, when I'm trying to use port `587` and `tls` there's error too.
Would you please let me know what's wrong?


The host php version is `5.4`.

this is my code:

```
require_once ("../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

class mailSender
{

    protected $address;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $cc;
    protected $bcc;

    protected $body;

    protected $mailer;


    public function __construct( $host, $port, $usn, $psw, $isSMTP = true )
    {

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer(true);

        //$this->mailer->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
        $this->mailer->Host       = $host; //"smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $this->mailer->Port       = $port; //465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server




        if( $isSMTP == true )
        {

            $this->mailer->IsSMTP();
            //$this->mailer->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
            $this->mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $this->mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier

        }

        $this->mailer->Username   = $usn; //"yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $this->mailer->Password   = $psw; //"yourpassword";            // GMAIL password


        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        $this->mailer->IsHTML(true);

        //set High priority to prevent going to SPAM folder
        $this->mailer->Priority = 1;
        $this->mailer->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: High");
        $this->mailer->AddCustomHeader("Importance: High");


    }//function __construct





    public function send( $address, $senderName, $replyAddr, $replyName, $fromAddr, $fromName, $subject, $body, $attachment = false, $cc = false, $bcc = false )
    {


      try {

          //$this->mailer->AddReplyTo( $replyAddr, $replyName);
          $this->mailer->AddAddress($address, $senderName);
          $this->mailer->SetFrom($fromAddr, $fromName);
          $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($replyAddr, $replyName);
          $this->mailer->Subject = $subject; //'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
          $this->mailer->AltBody = 'در صورتی که قادر به تماشای محتوای ای-میل نیستید از یک نمایشگر ای-میل تحت HTML استفاده کنید!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
          $this->mailer->MsgHTML($body);
              //$this->mailer->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
              //$this->mailer->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
              //$this->mailer->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
          $send = $this->mailer->Send();

          if( $send )
          {
              return true;

          }
          else
          {
              return false;

          }
      }//try send
      catch( Exception $e )
      {

          return false;

      }//catch

    }//function Send

}//class mailSender
```

***`Thanks in Advance`***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782689/smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-connection-timed-out-110-with-phpmail

Comment: Has your webserver been configured properly to allow phpmailer?

Comment: @Crecket Would you please mention what kind of configure do you mean?

Comment: @Kiya what is your webserver right now? On xampp I usually have to configure my php.ini and sendmail.ini. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) is a example off the php settings you may need to configure

Comment: As you will no doubt have seen in many of the answers on StackOverflow, you're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. [Get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [*read the docs*](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki). When you've done all that, ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be your gmail acct is locked. Try the unlock captcha:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.

Also check your account setting called ***Allow less secure apps*** here:

https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps